# Creating a custom back button across my app

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I’m trying to change the default look of Navigation Controller back button across my app.

I would like to use and image(icon) and remove the “Back” text.
This code stretched the image across the button and does not remove the button title.

```
let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "icon_back")!
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonBackgroundImage(backImg, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)
```

An recommendation how to do is inside AppDelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions)?

Comment: Create a base subclass of UIViewController with it.

Comment: @ElTomato Can you explain that a bit more please? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way of doing is just create one `BaseViewController` for your project which is derived from `UIViewController`. You can have on common method in `BaseViewController` to create your `custom leftBarButton` in every viewController. The remaining viewController in your project should be `derived from this BaseViewController`,

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createLeftBarButton(image: #Pass image here#, width: #Pass width of your image view#) // Create custom back bar button.
    }

    /**Create cutom back bar button*/
    func createLeftBarButton(image: UIImage?, width: CGFloat) {

        let backButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 50))
        backButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        backButton.imageView?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: width)
        backButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        backButton.setImage(image, for: .highlighted)
        backButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(leftBarButtonItemPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        let leftItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: backButton)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem

    }

    /**Custom back bar button pressed. So handle here*/
    func leftBarButtonItemPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        view.endEditing(true) // End editing if any.
        if isViewControllerPresented() { // Check view controller is presented or pushed
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // Dismiss ViewController if presented
        } else {
            _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) // Pop ViewController if pushed
        }

    }

    /**To check whether view controller is presented or pushed.*/
    func isViewControllerPresented() -> Bool {

        if self.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self {
            return true
        }
        if (self.navigationController != nil && self.navigationController?.presentingViewController?.presentedViewController == self.navigationController) && self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count == 1 {
            return true
        }
        if self.tabBarController?.presentingViewController is UITabBarController {
            return true
        }
        return false

    }

  }

// Sub class your remaining viewControllers like this.
class FirstViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() // When calling this super method, the custom back bar button will be created for you
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can doing this by setting the `navigationItem`'s `BackButtonBackgroundImage`;

also you can set the appearance for global effect:

`let item = UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UINavigationBar.self])
item.setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment(-10, for: .default)    item.setBackButtonBackgroundImage(youImage, for: .normal, barMetrics: .default)`

---

for removing the back title, you can do like this:

`@implementation UINavigationItem (BackItem)`

`-(UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem {
    UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
    item.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    return item;
}`

`@end`